# CSS Child & Parent Selector

Tags: css, css-selectors, parent-child, parent, children

I am currently working on a Connect 4 game where the board is set up as a table with buttons in the td.

```
    <table class="board">
        <tr>
            <td><button type="button"></button> </td>
            <td><button type="button"></button> </td>
            <td><button type="button"></button> </td>
            <td><button type="button"></button> </td>
            <td><button type="button"></button> </td>
            <td><button type="button"></button> </td>
            <td><button type="button"></button> </td>
        </tr>
```

I figured out the answer to my question but what I need to know is why I got the answer I did.

When trying to edit the button I initially had my CSS like this:

```
button {
   height: 100px;
   width: 100px;
   border-radius: 50%;
   margin: 1px;
   border: 1px solid black;
```

}

The height, width, and border changed but the border-radius and the margin had no changes.

However, when I changed the CSS to this:

```
.board button {
   height: 100px;
   width: 100px;
   border-radius: 50%;
   margin: 1px;
   border: 1px solid black;
```

}

All the changes occurred. Why did that happen? And thanks to the contributors.

Comment: The code you say doesn't work works fine https://jsfiddle.net/j08691/49ug1bjt/

Comment: Which is why I asked the question because I know it is supposed to work. However, after you answered I think its a Chrome thing because I opened the program in another browser and it worked. Thanks, j08691.